# Delphi: Correct way to store objects fetched from TObjectList

Tags: delphi, oop, tobjectlist

This example is of course simplified, but basically I have a main form that triggers another form (frmSettings) with

```
function Execute(var aSettings: TSettings):Boolean
```

`TSettings` is my own object created in main form for keeping track of the settings.

In this newly opened form (frmSettings) I fetch a `TMyObjectList` that is a descendant from `TObjectList`.
It's filled with `TMyObj`.

I then fill a `TListBox` with values from that TMyObjectList.

the code:

```
...

FMyObjectList : TMyObjectList;
property MyObjectList: TMyObjectList read getMyObjectList;

...

function TfrmSettings.getMyObjectList: TMyObjectList ;
begin
    If not Assigned(FMyObjectList) then FMyObjectList := TMyObjectList.Create(True)
    Result := FMyObjectList;
end;

function TfrmSettings.Execute(var aSettings: TSettings): Boolean;
begin

    //Fill myObjectList
    FetchObjs(myObjectList);

    //Show list to user
    FillList(ListBox1, myObjectList);

    //Show form        
    ShowModal;

    Result := self.ModalResult = mrOk;

    if Result then
    begin
        // Save the selected object, but how??

        // Store only pointer? Lost if list is destroyed.. no good
        //Settings.selectedObj := myObjectList.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];

        // Or store a new object? Have to check if exist already?
        If not Assigned(Settings.selectedObj) then Settings.selectedObj := TMyObj.Create;
        Settings.selectedObj.Assign(myObjectList.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];);
    end;

end;

procedure TfrmSettings.FillList(listBox: TListBox; myObjectList: TMyObjectList);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    listBox.Clear;
    With myObjectList do
    begin
        for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
        begin
            //list names to user
            listBox.Items.Add(Items[i].Name);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmSettings.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FreeAndNil(FMyObjectList);
end;
```

Storing just the pointer doesn't seem as a good idea, as triggering the settings form again, recreates the list, and the original object would be lost even if user hits "cancel"

So storing a copy seems better, using assign to get all the properties correct. And first checking if I already have an object.

```
        If not Assigned(Settings.selectedObj) then Settings.selectedObj := TMyObj.Create;
        Settings.selectedObj.Assign(myObjectList.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];);
```

Should I move those two lines to a method instead like `Settings.AssignSelectedObj(aMyObj:TMyObj)`

Does this look correct or am I implementing this the wrong way? 
Something more/less needed?

I need some guidelines so I feel more secure that I don't open up for memory leaks and other trouble.

Other than that reviewing the code a bit, the real question is: **Is this the correct way to store my SelectedObject in the settings class?**

Comment: If not Assigned(FMyObjectList) then FMyObjectList.Create(True); is not correct - you should have written: If not Assigned(FMyObjectList) then FMyObjectList := TMyObjectList.Create(True);

Comment: @A.Bouchez: True. As stated, it's example code, so sometimes you hit de delete button too hard. thanks for pointing it out though, edited!

Answer (score 1):

**Is this the correct way to store the selected object in the settings?**

Probably not. Your settings class should not depend on the form in any way. What if you decide to create and destroy your form dynamically each time the user opens the settings? In this case your settings would hold an invalid object reference.

IMHO it is better to store the object list in the settings together with the index of the selected object. The form should just access the settings, fill the list box and modify the selected object index after the user confirmed with OK.

<strike>You are producing a memory leak in your code. You create a `TObjectList` as a local variable but you never free it. And if you free the local variable, the object references in the listbox will be invalid. You have two options:</strike>

- Store the object list as a member variable of your form, create in the `FromCreate` event handler and destroy it in the `FormDestroy` event handler. You can then safely use object references in your list box.
- Store the object list somewhere outside and pass it into the form as a parameter of the `Execute` method. In this scenario, you can also safely use object references.

Comment: Sorry, i lost some code in my attempt so simplify it. In reality i have a property that keeps ths objectlist.
Post is now edited

Comment: I thought I skipped that problem by doing an Settings.Assign, with that the Settings object has nothing to do with the form. 
Storing the whole list instead, wouldn't that require more memory?
Anyhow, the list needs to be updated every time the frmSettings is opened, because it gets the values from a Database, and the values can change.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment, that TSettings doesn't have anything to do with the form since I create a new object in TSettings?

Answer (score 0):

I would rename myObjectList to GlobalObjectList, and move it out of the class.  It can be declared in the form, but create/free in the initialization/finalization sections.  During initialization, after you create the list, populate it from the ini file (or wherever you store it).  Now you can access it from anywhere that has your unit in the Uses.

Comment: Sorry, i lost some code in my attempt so simplify it. In reality i have a property that keeps ths objectlist. Post is now edited

Answer (score 0):

What about the serialization of TSettings? Put your settings in some published properties, then let the RTTI save its content:

```
type
  TSettings = class(TPersistent)
  public
    function SaveAsText: UTF8String;
  end;

function TSettings.SaveAsText: UTF8String;
begin
var
  Stream1, Stream2: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Stream1.WriteComponent(MyComponent);
    ObjectBinaryToText(Stream1, Stream2);
    SetString(result,PAnsiChar(Stream2.Memory),Stream2.Size);
  finally
    Stream1.Free;
    Stream2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Then your settings can be stored in a text file or text string.

It's just one solution. But storing settings as text is very handy. We use such an approach in our framework, [to store settings via a code-generated user interface](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/SQLite3UIOptions.pas). A settings tree is created, from a tree of TPersistent instances.

Comment: The question was really about: Is this the correct way to store the selected object in the settings?
Not how to store my TSettings object for later, but thanks for sharing that code anyway, seems useful and I might use it in other projects!

Comment: @Bulan Yes I think I understood your problem. But using such a shared TObjectList sounds a less good idea than a TPersistent hierarchy. With a list, you have only a linear list of properties; with a TPersistent hierarchy, you can embedded classes within classes, then display your settings not as a list but as a tree, which is better for the User experience, IMHO. Text storage is only the "bonus" part of this. Of course I don't correct your code problem, just propose an architecture change.